# Adjust UISearchBar when becoming active in a UITableView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchbar

Having set `viewForHeaderInSection` to be a `UISearchBar` for `section = 0`, in order to have it at the top of my `UITableView`; I want crazy stuff to happen when this it active. Therefore, I'm thinking that I want the section to have 0 rows when the UISearchBar is inactive and then adjust accordingly to what I want, when it is active.

Therefore I have

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

But then my table reloads the section and I lose firstResponder for the search bar. Should I follow the previous code snippet with `[self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder]` then my problem is still not fixed, I guess maybe because of the animation property.

What is the sexy way to fix this kind of issue? Should I use `tableView:reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` instead? That would seem a bit too forced. There must be a better way.

I'm guessing I'm not the first one to want to do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I've always added my search bars as subviews of my `UITableView` rather than header views, and therefore they function independently of the table, so reloading your rows shouldn't affect the search bar.

Comment: How do you make sure it works well with positioning and scolling?

Comment: in `viewDidLoad` I set the search bar hidden, kinda tucked up out of the way with `[myTable setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, self.searchBar.frame.size.height) animated:NO];` Other than that, it just appears at the top anytime they scroll to the top. If you want it always visible, you may want to add it outside the tableView.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out in a couple of hours.